# Does Apple keep sending notifications after they have been disabled?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

It is widely known that you can disable the reception of Apple notifications from the applications that allow it. But does anyone know if the disabling is made locally (ignoring the notifications Apple sends to the app), or does Apple stop sending you notifications from it's servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally discovered in depth how Apple Push Notifications work: if you disable the notifications on one app, Apple does not know of this behavior instantly, so it keeps sending notifications to the device whenever they are created. These notifications will try to reach your app, but instead they will be sent back to Apple with an error code. That feedback will be sent to your servers (the ones that order Apple to distribute your app notifications). You will have to check that information regularly so that if one device has returned a certain amount of "errors", it means that the user has disabled the notifications (or has even uninstalled the app)

Further information: [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1)